# can you compute t statistics in python without libraries? if so can I have an example?

Tags: python, statistics

if so can I have an example?
I want to have a better computational skills in statistics but can't find any examples without using libraries

Comment: What is your question? Asking for __examples or links to learn statistics in Python__ seems off-topic. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

a good start point can be the [statistic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) library:

The source code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/statistics.py)

Code is in pure python and readable.